# How to change activity hierarchy?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I build a project with many activities. Every time, when I was creating new activity, I set a hierarchy parent. But I decided to make an activity with animation, which should be first. I tried to change some information inside manifest file and set the new one activity as the starting activity, but I'm doing something wrong and all the project is crushing. Ofc, I will be keep going and trying to change the manifest file, but maybe I can do that in an easier way using Eclipse tools?

--EDIT--
I solved my problem, it was a quite small mistake. I was just setting wrong layout and forget to change one more thing. I'm not a specialist yet on this topic, but maybe for other readers I will put here some information how to change the hierarchy using manifest file. If I will make any mistakes here, feel free to edit.

Ok, so let's suppose we have our project with a few activities. Inside Manifest file we can find some information about activities, this informations are between markers: . So, it may looks like:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mastermind.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mastermind.StartGameActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_game"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.mastermind.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.mastermind.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
<activity
            android:name="com.example.mastermind.NewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_new_activity" >
        </activity>
```

Now we want to change the MainActivity, which is the first one and set as the first one the NewActivity. We only need to change the name of activity which contains markers:

```
<intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
```

for the name of NewActivity and also set it's layout, like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mastermind.NewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_new_activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mastermind.StartGameActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_game"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.mastermind.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.mastermind.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
<activity
            android:name="com.example.mastermind.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

That should be Ok.

Comment: How have you modified your manifest file?

Comment: Well, I changed name of the activity which has <intent-filter> with <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> for the name of new Activity and the one, which was earlier as the main activity set as others.

Comment: And it is still launching the original?

Comment: No. After the change the application is crushing at the beginning

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: There appers only a toast - Application XYZ has stopped unexpectedly

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest file locate `category.LAUNCHER`:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /><!-- This -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

The `category.LAUNCHER` declares your launch `Activity`.

Comment: I had this, so I changed only the name of activity which contains this, and the old one set in the same way as other activities, but then my application crushed while startup

Comment: Do your new launch activity contain onCreate()?